# Only Office does not support custom delimiter for Importing CSV

Tags: import-csv, onlyoffice

Recently, I import a CSV using Only Office Desktop Edition, but it doesn't allow custom delimiter such as `|`.
Please support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

OnlyOffice Documentserver support custom delimiters from version 4.4.
OnlyOffice DesktipEditors will be released with support of thome soon.